# Why aren't sync.WaitGroup, sync.Mutex reference types like channel, slices?

Tags: go, concurrency

If Waitgroups and Mutex always needs to be passed by reference always, can't we make it a reference type (forbid the use of them as pass by value)? I mean is there any use case where we need to use them pass by value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you pass any argument as value, the value will get copied. Any modification these arguments will be local the the `func`. When the `func` exits those changes will be gone.

In case of a `WaitGroup` or `Mutex` you do not want this, as you want to share the state. If all modifications were local, you could not sync anything, as you would have many different copies with different states.

One valid case could be that you *want* to copy a `WaitGroup` or `Mutex`, but that would be very implicit code and hard for another developer to understand/maintain.

Comment: I totally agree with what you say. Does it make sense to forbid pass by value of waitgroups and mutex?

Comment: Hi. I just extended my answer. Hope that helps.

Comment: Still there is this question of when would we want to copy a WaitGroup/ Mutex ?

Comment: That depends on your program or what you want to achieve. But I think it is always better to explicitly create a new one.

Comment: Exactly the point, It's always better to create a new one. So can we restrict the pass by value ability of them?

Comment: You are welcome. If this really helped an upvote and an accept would make me very happy. :)